# iOSの画面共有をwindowsアプリで受信する方法を知りたい

Tags: ios

Androidであれば「画面録画→エンコード→サーバーに送信する」方法を見つけることができましたが、iOSで同様のことを実装している文献を見つけることができませんでした。

iOSの基本機能でmacへのミラーリングを行うことができますが、windowsで映像を受け取ることはできないでしょうか？
技術的にどのような選択肢があるのかご教授いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

[5kPlayer](https://www.5kplayer.com/#5KPlayer)のようなフリーウェアがあるようです。
これで不足な場合は、

`windows` `iphone` `screen mirroring`

をキーワードにインターネット検索すると有料ソフトがいくつか見つかるようです。